# Trying to use PdfStamper and MemoryStream to add data to existing PDF

Tags: c#, itext, memorystream, pdfstamper

My goal is to use `SetField` to change the PDF from code and then use the API to download it. API works and the PDF can be downloaded but no changes were made.

And after a days work I have to ask for help.

What I try to achieve is to get the File back with the changes set.
I get the filled values, and with the `GetField` I see that the field is set, but then again when i download it no changes are in the PDF.

This is the code that I use.

```
        var pth = $"{Environment.CurrentDirectory}.Services\\Pdf\\plan2.pdf";
        PdfReader pdfReader = null;
        byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(pth);
        try
        {
            using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                MemoryStream inputStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);

                pdfReader = new PdfReader(inputStream);

                PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, outStream);
                pdfStamper.AcroFields.GenerateAppearances = true;

                pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetField("registersubject", "testSubject");

                pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
                pdfStamper.FreeTextFlattening = true;
                pdfStamper.Writer.CloseStream = false;
                pdfStamper.Close();

                return outStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
```

Comment: This again!!!! With MemoryStream after you fill the object you must set position to zero before using.  Answered same question with PDF file a few weeks ago.

Comment: @jdweng `ToArray()` ignores the position.

Comment: @jdweng Thank you very much, that solved it. Removed the `ToArray()` and set the position to zero.